# Browser issues - gets redirected to adware

Tags: ipad, web-browsing, spam

When I open web pages, the page automatically redirects to "youradexchange.com" or some other ad web site. Not been able to resolve the issue.

Comment: happens this on your ipad? Can you add that in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen on all websites?

Some sites do this. For example, The Pirate Bay or EZTV - when you click to scroll, they will open a new tab to show you ads.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to download and run [Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware for Mac](https://it.malwarebytes.org/antimalware/mac/). It will detect most adwares and remove them automatically.

Also, see [this article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203987) from Apple's Knowledge base about how to remove adware.